# Image created does not display correctly

Tags: opencv

Hi I am using following function to create an image.

Mat im(584, 565, CV_8UC1, imgg);
imwrite("Output_Image.tif", im);

but the problem is that when I display the image "Output_Image.tif". Right hand side portion is overlapped onto the left handside portion. I am not able to understand what is happening. Please explain as I am beginner to opencv. Thanks[image: This is the Output_image.tiff]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the image is CV_8UC1 (colospace grayscale)?

It looks like the image is an BGR image (Blue, Green, Red) and when you use an CV_8UC3 image as an CV_8UC1 image it does that.

Change this line:

```
 Mat im(584, 565, CV_8UC1, imgg);
```

To this line:

```
Mat im(584, 565, CV_8UC3, imgg);
```

EDIT for mixChannels() (see comments):

C++: void mixChannels(const Mat* src, size_t nsrcs, Mat* dst, size_t ndsts, const int* fromTo, size_t npairs)

the Mat* dst is an array of Mats which must be allocated with the right size and depth before calling mixChannels. In that array your cv::Mats will really have 1 channel.

Code Example:

```
cv::Mat rgb(500, 500, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
cv::Mat redChannel(rgb.rows, rgb.cols, cv_8UC1);
cv::Mat greenChannel(rgb.rows, rgb.cols, cv_8UC1);
cv::Mat blueChannel(rgb.rows, rgb.cols, cv_8UC1);

cv::Mat outArray[] = {redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel };

int from_to[] = {0,0 , 1,2 , 3,3};
cv::mixChannels(&rgb, 1, outArray, 3, from_to, 3);
```

Its a little bit more complex than the split() function so heres a link to the documentary, especially the from_to array is hard to understand at first

Link to documentation:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels

Comment: Initial Image 3 channels

Comment: can you post some more code? How do you get the imgg data? How do you extract one channel from the image?

Comment: But I extracted one channel and applied some operations on it like imgg[x][y]=255-(ch[0].at<uchar>(x,y); and then I used Mat im(584,565,CV_8UC1,imgg).

Comment: Btw I extracted the channel using vector<Mat> ch and split(image,ch)

Comment: The split function is not the best function for that. Try the function cv::mixChannels().

Comment: please give me the syntax for that. Thanks

Comment: the split function somehow keeps the image type. So your split is still an BGR image. The mixChannels() function copys the content of the channels of the src image into another mat. So your image type is a real CV_8UC1 and it should be displayed correctly.

Comment: Mat ch = Mat(584,565,CV_8UC1);
 int from_to[] = { 1, 0};
 mixChannels(&img, 1, &ch, 1,from_to, 1);

Comment: You have to use the mixChannels function on the original BGR image. So you need to use the mixChannels function at the point where you use your split() right now.

Comment: yes im using it on original image.                                 Mat img = imread("image.tif", 1);

Comment: I will test this on monday and edit my post according to it. I'm currently not at a PC with an development environment. I know that this works, try playing around with it. I'll give you the answer on monday :)

Comment: Thanks Flocke. But this is what im trying to do. There is a minor change in code. Now you may b able to find the mistake....

Comment: For the following code:
Mat img = imread("image.tif", 1);
Mat ch = Mat(584,565,CV_8UC1);
int from_to[] = { 1, 0};
mixChannels(&img, 1, &ch, 1,from_to, 1);
imwrite("green_image.tif", ch);

It gives correct output upto this point.

For the following code output is not correct eventhough there is slight change in code.
short imgg[584][565];
for (x = 0; x < 584; x++)
for (y = 0; y < 565; y++)
 imgg[x][y] = 255 - ((short)ch.at<uchar>(x, y));
imwrite("Output_image.tif", imgg);

Comment: Only thing i can think of without testing it is that the imwrite function will use a CV_16U "channel" for an image that is marked as .*tif (opencv just looks at the extension of the filename you give it :"output_image.tif"). Try this: imgg.cvtColor(imgg, imgg, CV_8UC1); imwrite("Output_image.tif", imgg);

Comment: The thing is, that you create short imgg[584][565] and feed that into the imwrite. So opencv automaticly adds a depth to the picture. the first imwrite you use (the one were the output is correct) is real image data marked as CV_8U1 and thats why it works the first time.

Comment: Thanks Flocke,I found the problem. It was with the data type of imgg. It should be uchar. Thanks for your support. I learnt a new function mixChannels().

Comment: Cool! The cvt function should have done the same :) Have fun with opencv :)